# MAx peak to peak of ES without clipping?

Tags: transistors, resistors, bjt

This is an exam problem in which my instructor gave the answers but no work. Any one has an idea of how to solve it;FOM(figure of merit)= 25/125, RL=15 ohms, Rx=250 ohms, r1,r2,vee,vcc, are not given. There is more info in the table in the image about vbe, etc.? The answer is ES=161.052 volts peak to peak. OHH and at 42 degrees above ambient the transistors dissipates 25 watts of power I tried somethings regarding ES which is ES=vin/zin*(Rx+zin), however I am stuck at finding vin and zin(since r1 an r2 are not given), and obtaining the thermal model didnt help me. My professor said the key to this problem lies on realizing the relationship between the TA or temperature at ambient and some other value, which I forgot, and is why I am here.[image]

Answer (score 1):

The question is confusing, because while it asks explicitly about "clipping" distortion, the rest of the data seems to imply that the limit is a thermal one, which does not produce clipping *per se*.

But let's follow the reasoning regarding the thermal limit.

First of all, with a bias level of 0.01% of the peak current (this turns out to be about 1.4 mA), the amplifier is operating essentially pure "class B". The maximum theoretical efficiency of a class-B amplifier on a sinewave signal (when it is just barely clipping at the supply voltage) is π/4, or 78.5%.

Each Darlington pair is limited to a temperature rise of 42°C, using a heatsink that has a thermal resistance of 0.2 °C/W, so that means we can have each pair dissipating 42 °C / 0.2 °C/W = 210 W.

This represents 21.5 % of the input power, which will then be 210 W/21.5% = 977 W, and since we have two pairs, the total input power will be 1954 W. The power delivered to the load will be 1954 W * 78.5% = 1533 W.

Since we know that the load resistance is 15Ω, we can calculate that the RMS current is \$\sqrt{1533 W / 15\Omega} = 10.1 A\$ and the RMS voltage is \$\sqrt{1533 W * 15\Omega} = 151 V\$.

Since the voltage gain of this amplifier is unity, the maximum continuous sinewave input signal is \$151 V_{RMS} * 2 * \sqrt{2} = 427 V_{P-P}\$.

Comment: You logic seems sound but the answer is wrong. Its suppose to be 161 vp-p, which is what my professor gave me. And the thermal resistance is Rtheta SA not r theta CS. You need to get the thermal model to get R theta SA, thx to u i figured out how.

Comment: I said up front that the question is confusing/incomplete. I just followed the reasoning about the thermal issues to demonstrate why you might come up with a different answer. In other words, there isn't enough information in the question to come up with the given answer.